# changing image size independent of scene size

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

I have three images and I want change the images size based on the scene size (default size is 1024x768). After each image has completely loaded I call bindableUtils.setter to set width/height when scene size changes but I don't know how to make a pointer or something like that. I'm using a public var img, but it only works with the last complete image.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.binding.utils.BindingUtils;

            public var img:Image;
            private function setterWidth(newWidth:Number):void
            {
                img.width = img.content.width * newWidth / 1024;
            }
            private function setterHeight(newHeight:Number):void
            {
                img.height = img.content.height * newHeight / 768;
            }

            protected function image_completeHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                img = event.target as Image;
                BindingUtils.bindSetter(setterWidth, this, "width");
                BindingUtils.bindSetter(setterHeight, this, "height");
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:Image id="img1" source="img1.jpg" complete="image_completeHandler(event)" />
    <mx:Image id="img2" source="img2.jpg" complete="image_completeHandler(event)" y="60"/>
    <mx:Image id="img3" source="img3.jpg" complete="image_completeHandler(event)" y="120"/>
</s:Application>
```

I don't use a for each image extra bindSetter function.

Maybe my idea on how I can change the size of image based on the size of the scene is wrong. How would you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:Image id="img1" source="img1.jpg" scaleX="{width/1024}" scaleY="{height/768}" />
<mx:Image id="img2" source="img2.jpg" scaleX="{width/1024}" scaleY="{height/768}" y="60"/>
<mx:Image id="img3" source="img3.jpg" scaleX="{width/1024}" scaleY="{height/768}" y="120"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try [`percentWidth`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#percentWidth) and [`percentHeight`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#percentHeight)?